# How to get adwords conversions along with gclids via python adwords API?

Tags: python, google-ads-api

am wondering which of the reports from https://developers.google.com/adwords/api/docs/appendix/reports/ I should query to get conversion_name, count, value and gclid?

Doubleclick search has https://developers.google.com/doubleclick-search/v2/reference/conversion/get , cannot find something similar for Adwords API.

Thanks a lot in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I sense this answer may be a little a disappointing! I do not think its possible to get a report with gclids and conversions. There is a report 'click_performance_report' which contains the gclid for each click, however there are no columns for conversions. Your best bet is to use a third party tracking tool to log gclids and conversion names/values.

Conversion data is only available within the following reports:

```
ACCOUNT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
ADGROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
AD_CUSTOMIZERS_FEED_ITEM_REPORT
AD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
AGE_RANGE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
AUDIENCE_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
AUTOMATIC_PLACEMENTS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
BID_GOAL_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
BUDGET_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
CAMPAIGN_AD_SCHEDULE_TARGET_REPORT
CAMPAIGN_GROUP_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
CAMPAIGN_LOCATION_TARGET_REPORT
CAMPAIGN_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
CRITERIA_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
DESTINATION_URL_REPORT
DISPLAY_KEYWORD_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
DISPLAY_TOPICS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
FINAL_URL_REPORT
GENDER_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
GEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
KEYWORDLESS_CATEGORY_REPORT
KEYWORDLESS_QUERY_REPORT
KEYWORDS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
PARENTAL_STATUS_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
PLACEHOLDER_FEED_ITEM_REPORT
PLACEHOLDER_REPORT
PLACEMENT_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
PRODUCT_PARTITION_REPORT
SEARCH_QUERY_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
SHOPPING_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
URL_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
USER_AD_DISTANCE_REPORT
VIDEO_PERFORMANCE_REPORT
```